# How to set-up/use a 2D dimensional array as member of a Java class

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I am aware this might be a super-basic Java question, but I am a complete newbie in Java.

Let's assume I have the following two classes in Java:

```
public class Cell {

    private Integer value;

    public Integer setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}

public class Grid {

    private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[9][9];

    public void setCell(int row, int column, Integer value){
        cells[row][column].setValue(value);
    }

}
```

Let alone for the fact that the code is unsafe if row or column exceed 8, my understanding is that Grid allocates the memory for 9 x 9 Cells, so that the method setCell(1,1, 10) should be ok (i.e. not cause a NullPointerException), right? However, when making JUnit tests for this cases this is exactly the error I've got. I can only overcome this error if instead of

```
    cells[row][column].setValue(value);
```

I use

```
    cells[row][column] = new Cell();
    cells[row][column].setValue(value);
```

But I have the impression that I am instantiating Cell twice. What am I missing here? Is the instruction

```
    private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[9][9];
```

just allocating the structure (i.e. pointers) to hold the Cell objects without actually reserving memory for the objects themselves?

Thanks!

@Tryskele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Cell[9][9];` creates array which can hold instances of `Cell` objects, but doesn't actually fill it with new instances of `Cell` class. Instead it is filled with `null`.

You may find it strange at first but there is a reason for such behaviour and is quite simple:

- compiler can't decide which constructor should be used,
- but even if it could know that, it still doesn't know which data should be passed as constructor arguments

Like in case of `File` class which doesn't have no-argument constructor `new File()` (what would such file represent?) it is programmers responsibility to decide *how* to initialize new objects and *when* they should be placed in array.

Most common way would be doing it in constructor, or if you have lot of them you can also use initialization block (which will be moved to each constructor) like:

```
class Grid {

    private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[9][9];
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<cells.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<cells[i].length; j++){
                cells[i][j] = new Cell();//lets use no-argument constructor
            }
        }
    }

    public void setCell(int row, int column, Integer value){
        cells[row][column].setValue(value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating an array (of any dimension) of any object type, all elements of the array are initialized to `null`.  No object creation takes place implicitly, so no `Cell` objects are created yet.  Only the array is created with this line:

```
private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[9][9];
```

That is the reason that you must use this line:

```
cells[row][column] = new Cell();
```

You aren't creating the `Cell` twice.  You can only create the `Cell` explicitly, and you must do that once.

Answer (score 2):

```
private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[9][9];
```

does not create 81 instances of Cell, it creates an array which will store those objects.